# Null Coalessing not returning correct value

Tags: c#

It is my understanding that the below line should return an empty string "" in the case the Datagrid cell was empty.

```
string proxyuser = this.dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString() ?? "";
```

For some reason, I"m still receiving a null reference error on the init line.

Comment: You probably need to protect against `Value` being null, by doing `string proxyuser = this.dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value?.ToString() ?? "";` Run it under a debugger and inspect the various parts of the expression to see which is null, and fix accordingly.

Comment: `(string)null ?? ""` will return `string.Empty`. One of the previous properties is null (`dataGridView2`, or `SelectedRows[0]`, etc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's likely a chance one of the other parts are null, I recommend trying out null propagation. (where a `?.` will check if the current left part is null first before continueing past the dot, otherwise, it'll return a null, and then giving back the empty string)

For example:

```
string proxyuser = this.dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0]?.Cells[3]?.Value?.ToString() ?? "";
```

Comment: Cells[3]?.Value.ToString() can still fail. If Cells[3] is null, Value.ToString() will also fail and you should use the null propator operator at each step : Cells[3]?.Value?.ToString()

Comment: I'm not sure if the `Value` is nullable in this case, but in case of doubt, it's a safe practise to apply it at every step indeed.